# CPU or Memory intensive for running Oracle VM on laptop

Tags: performance, virtual-machines

Say a 2011 laptop with Windows 7 installed by default, and have Oracle VirtualBox VM running another Ubuntu on it. The spec is like 2nd generation Intel i7, 8G DDR3 DRAM. In this scenario, is CPU, Memory, or any other part may be the bottleneck? How to measure the matrices and figure which part needs to be improved. Can the community give some suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by Oracle VM? Are you running Ubuntu in an Oracle VirtualBox VM? Oracle database under Ubuntu in an Oracle VirtualBox VM?

Comment: @Joe, I meant Oracle VirtualBox VM, fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the other repiles have made good points, don't forget that running multiple VMs can be very disk intensive as well. My laptop is more than capable of running 2/3/4 VMS but it would struggle running 3 or 4 due to the thrashing of the disk. If you are running from a RAID or SSD the performace may be a little better...just something to think about.

Answer (score 1):

> In this scenario, is CPU, Memory, or any other part may be the bottleneck?

You tell us. So far you simply did not say anything remotely relevant. It is not important to know what OS you run, but what APPLICATIONS are running. If they are CPU bottlenecking, the cpu will bottleneck. If they are memory intensive, but low CPU, guess what - the memory will be the bottlenek.

What you say is "I got a truck, is it big enough" and that is it ;) No more information.

Comment: if it's on Windows, there will be several VS2010 instances and SSMS (SQL Server 2008) running for development. If it's on Ubuntu, that might be several eclipse instances. Meanwhile, probably have several word docs/spreadsheet/Outlook opened.

Comment: You are dead. Seriously. I dont know what you tlk of, but in my world SQL Server runs on multiple discs and more memory than a laptop has ;)

Answer (score 1):

It depends.. CPU won't likely be the first bottleneck. Use a SSD drive for storage and don't overcommit your RAM.   If you have a sata drive,  that will be you first bottleneck with more than one or two vm's.   With only 8GB of system memory and looking to run multiple SQL vm's you will like hit RAM walls too.   Watch perf mon for page/swap use and disk queue lengths for indications of RAM or disk IO shortfalls.